# How do I convert JSON date to UTC date format for an Azure site?

Tags: json, date, azure, utc

When I deploy my site to Azure, All the dates that I get back from JSON are off by a day.
I need help converting them  to UTC format? **I am in the EAST US**.

My Date format in JSON

```
"DateEntered":"\/Date(1395115200000-0400)\/","DateReNegotiated":"\/Date(1401249600000-0400)\/","DateReceived":"\/Date(1395115200000-0400)\/","DateRequestComp":"\/Date(1395720000000-0400)\/","DisposDate":"\/Date(1399953600000-0400)\/"
```

How I currently convert them to readable dates:

```
var dr_date = $.date(inv.DateEntered);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here, someone created a js file for different formats (including UTC):

http://mvcworld.blogspot.com/2013/06/convert-json-date-to-javascript-date.html

```
var de_date = inv.DateEntered; //$.date(inv.DateEntered);
var d1_date = new Date(parseInt(de_date.substr(6)));
var d2_date = d1_date.format("UTC:mm/dd/yyyy");
```